# Sublime text 3 Theme background color

Tags: background, themes, sublimetext3

Trying to adjust the color of the area behind the tabs in the Sublime Text UI but cannot find the parameter to change in the tmTheme files.

Answer (score 0):

`.tmTheme` files do not provide colors for the tabs or the area behind them - this is all done via `.sublime-theme` UI themes. Open this file in Sublime with JSON syntax highlighting (you may need to install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to access it) and search for `"class": "tabset_control"`. In `Default.sublime-theme` (which is located in the `Theme - Default` package), this starts on Line 518:

```js
{
    "class": "tabset_control",

    "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
    "tint_index": 0,

    // this is what you're looking for
    "layer1.texture": "Theme - Default/tabset_background_transparent.png",
    "layer1.inner_margin": [2, 6],
    "layer1.opacity": 1.0,

    "content_margin": [3, 0, 3, 1],
    "tab_overlap": 17,
    "tab_width": 180,
    "tab_min_width": 48,
    "tab_height": 35,
    "mouse_wheel_switch": false
},
```

<sup>In other Sublime themes I've looked at, such as [`Soda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Soda), `layer1` is actually called `layer0`, which I don't think makes a difference as long as you don't use both.</sup>

So, since the background color is specified with a PNG, to change its appearance you'll have to fire up your favorite image editor and choose your own design. Keep it the same dimensions as the current file, and if you're using a Retina-compatible theme, make sure to make an `@2x` version as well.

Comment: This almost works, but a thin line of the color appears beween the tab and the text area. Any idea why this may be happening? I know an image would be helpful but I cannot upload one!

Comment: @HughWilliams is your new image **exactly** the same dimensions as the one you're replacing, and you haven't changed any other settings? You can add a screenshot to your original question.